# Javascript code leaking memory to DOM nodes - where is the Javascript reference

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have the following JavaScript code below running on my Chrome Browser. It inserts 2 buttons, one to insert a select Element with 100,000 options if the list does not already exist, and another button which deletes the list if it does exist.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      insertButtons()

      function insertSelectList(){
        let selectList = document.querySelector("#selectList")
        if(selectList!=null)return;
        selectList = document.createElement("select")
        selectList.setAttribute("id", "selectList")
        for(let i=0; i<100000; i++){
          let option = document.createElement("option")
          option.setAttribute("value", i)
          option.innerText = i
          selectList.appendChild(option)
        }
        document.body.appendChild(selectList)
      }

      function removeSelectList(){
        let selectList = document.querySelector("#selectList")
        if(selectList==null)return;
        selectList.remove()
      }

      function insertButtons(){
        let insertListBtn = document.createElement("button")
        let removeListBtn = document.createElement("button")
        
        insertListBtn.innerText = "Insert List"
        removeListBtn.innerText = "Remove List"

        insertListBtn.addEventListener("click", insertSelectList)
        removeListBtn.addEventListener("click", removeSelectList)

        document.body.appendChild(insertListBtn)
        document.body.appendChild(removeListBtn)
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My script seems to be leaking memory as per the chrome DEV tools memory tab's memory snapshot functionality. Using the 2 buttons, I create and delete a Select list a few times, and after doing this, the memory usage of my webpage shoots up (see image linked below for reference). The select lists that I have created and subsequently deleted seem to be hanging out in memory. When we view the second snapshot in comparison with the first, there is an increase in the option and select elements.

As per my understanding when an HTML node is removed from the DOM tree and there is no javascript reference to the node, it should be freed up by the garbage collector. Can someone please tell me why these select nodes and their option children are sticking around in memory? I dont see a javascript reference to the select nodes.

Chrome Dev Tools memory snapshots,
[image: screenshot 1]

Comment: Keep in mind, something becoming eligible for garbage collection does not mean that garbage collection will run immediately and clean it up.  It just means it is eligible to be cleaned the next time it runs.  That may not be the issue, but it is a point to be aware of.

Comment: I fail to see what the practical use  is to create 100000 option elements.

Comment: Warning to others who may take this logic and stick it in jsfiddle to play around with it.  Do so in a different browser to the one that you are normally using.  Trying to test it can result in it locking up your browser and forcing you to kill the program in the task manager.  Just a warning.

Comment: Human beings cannot deal with a list of 100,000 options. It's ridiculous, and it calls for a more thoroughly thought-out design.

Comment: @Pointy how this is related to the question? Also, I don't see author saying that this particular code will be used in a production as a part of UI. Author is trying to understand why the memory is leaking in this specific example and asking for assistance.

Comment: @trincot when doing a memory management test, the practical use of using a stupidly big number of objects is so that the results are obvious. Each HTMLOptionElement takes only ~28 Bytes to store, having only one or even a hundred would not make any perceptible difference in the global memory usage. Having ~3MB allocated is more visible.

Comment: Memory management is a complex beast and I'm afraid only the implementers will be able to tell exactly how the current version of this browser works. But in a nutshell, there is no memory leak here. If you push more pressure, (on my machine creating 5 such lists will do) and trigger a GC, then you'll see previous detached nodes to get collected (weirdly not all of them, only enough to make the memory usage back at 8MB). I don't think you should worry about this particular test.

Comment: @DmitryPapka a `<select>` with 100,000 options is a terrible idea, whether it works or not. That should be clear to anybody who's spent any time using a modern interface. It's related to the question because the question is about doing something ridiculous.

Comment: @Pointy, please note that the question **is not** about interface at all. It's about memory leak. You can replace 100,000 options with 50,000 options or with 100 or with 1 (like I did in my answer) and the problem will still be reproducible. Which means that amount of option elements is not related to **question** at all. I don't find the question ridiculous by the way. There are a lot of similar questions I found in internet, all of them without a clear answer, which means the problem exist but behaviour is pretty unclear. I find it interesting.

Comment: I don't disagree that it's interesting. Consider this: the question is going to be on the internet for a long time. Other people may find it. I don't want people thinking that 100,000 entries in a `<select>` is a good idea because I don't want to someday encounter a website where some designer had not realized that fact.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the reason of this behaviour (in fact, there are some related Chromium bugs open - you can find them easily if you search). But let me show you what I found.

One of the conditions for your detached elements be garbage collected is that there should be no variables referencing them. Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  // Note these variables outside the function!
  // Your DOM elements will be referenced even tho they're removed

  let div;
  let span;

  const append = () => {
    div = document.createElement('div');
    span = document.createElement('span');

    div.appendChild(span);

    span.remove()
    div.remove();
  }

  document.addEventListener('click', append);
</script>
```

As a result, your detached elements will be still in memory:

[image]

So let's move them inside our function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  const append = () => {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    let span = document.createElement('span');

    div.appendChild(span);

    span.remove()
    div.remove();
  }

  document.addEventListener('click', append);
</script>
```

Awesome! Function executed, internal variables not exist anymore, detached elements are not in memory:

[image]

However, I can find some weird behaviour if I replace `div` and `span` elements with `select` and `option`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  const append = () => {
    let select = document.createElement('select');
    let option = document.createElement('option');

    select.appendChild(option);

    option.remove()
    select.remove();
  }

  document.addEventListener('click', append);
</script>
```

Memory contains quite a lot of detached elements, including multiple `Detached InternalNode`, `Detached HTMLSlotElement`, `Detached HTMLDivElement` etc:

[image]

Honestly, it looks like a bug for me. Related to internal `select` tag implementation. But I might be wrong and missing something.

Just a couple of more observations:

1. Without a child `option` it works as expected:

   ```
    const append = () => {
      let select = document.createElement('select');
      document.body.append(select);
      select.remove();
    }
   ```

[image]

2. If function is executed not as a listener for some event (like `document` `click` event) but executed directly instead - everything works as expected as well:

   ```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      const append = () => {
        let select = document.createElement('select');
        let option = document.createElement('option');

        select.appendChild(option);
        document.body.append(select);

        option.remove()
        select.remove();
      };

      append();
    </script>
   ```

[image]

Comment: This is great digging! Especially that last detail is very incriminating; there really shouldn't be a difference between a function that is directly called, and one called upon an event

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry ! One thing I just noticed was that in my code's memory snapshots, the Select and Option elements are not detached, as you can see in the screenshot attached to my post. However, I cannot see them in the DOM tree in the elements tab of Chrome DEV tools. Do you have any idea why this is the case? When I ran your examples in chrome, the nodes did show up as detached elements in the memory snapshots.

Comment: Yeap, you're right. When I run my example, I can see both: Detached and Not Detached elements (like: `HTMLSpanElement` and `Detached HTMLSpanElement` in first example). I'm just filtering by "detached" keyword in the search bar of inspector on screenshots attached to the answer. But I believe that idea behind keeping these elements in memory (both detached and not) is the same. And yes, as you noticed, the DOM tree is updated correctly when you call `remove` method - the element is not present there. It's a memory problem. Unfortunately I don't know why this is happening.